# phpインストール済みのCentOS7にphpenvを入れて大丈夫かどうか

Tags: php, centos

タイトルの通りですが、以下の環境でphpenvを導入しました。

CentOS7
apache2.4
mariaDB
php7.1

phpenvのインストールは今の所完了しましたが、既存のphpとの競合などが気になっています。
調べても実例が見つからず、わかる方に教えて貰えるとありがたいです。

phpenvのインストールに参考にしたサイト
[CentOS7でPHPのバージョンを管理する](http://raichel.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/10/18/CentOS7%E3%81%A7PHP%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

追記：タイトルと全く違うことになってしまったので改めて書きます。
もともと直接インストールしたPHPをそのままにしてphpenvで運用しても問題は起こらないかを詳しい方にお聞きしたかったのです。
しかしphpenv自体がうまく動いておらず、それ以前の問題でした。（phpenvとapacheを連携していない状態だった）

そしてご案内いただいたように直接インストールしたPHPを削除しました。
その後下記サイトを主に参考にしてエラーを潰しながらphpenvとapacheを連携させることができました。
[phpenvとapacheを連携させる](https://www.kabanoki.net/509)

まだ検証が必要ですがとりあえず解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ディストリビューションやサードパーティーが提供するパッケージを利用した場合、Apacheの設定も勝手にやってくれることがほとんどですので、インストールするだけでPHPが利用できる状態になります。

phpenvを利用する場合も含めて､パッケージを利用せずにPHPをインストールした場合は、ApacheがPHPを読み込むための設定を自分でおこなう必要があります。

phpenvを使用する場合、普通の手順であれば自分のホームディレクトリ以下にインストールされますので、パッケージから導入したPHPと競合することはありませんが、上記の通りApacheの設定を変更しない限り、パッケージから導入したPHPが使われ続け、phpenvでインストールしたPHPが使われることはありません。

パッケージでインストールしたPHPを消さないと他の方法でインストールしたPHPが動かないわけではありません。

Answer (score 0):

以下のような手順で確認されては如何でしょうか。

念のため、phpenvでインストール済みのPHPバージョンを一覧表示して既存のPHPが認識されているのかを確認

```
$ phpenv versions
```

もし認識していないようであればyumでいったん削除してからphpenv経由でインストールし直す(設定ファイルや依存パッケージが削除されないかをよく確認してください）

```
$ yum remove php-x.x.xx
$ phpenv install x.x.xx
```

Comment: phpenv versionsではphpenvでインストールした5.6.30が表示され、php -vでは7.1.9が表示されています。まだphpenvを設定していないので試してみます。

Comment: phpenvで5.6.30を設定した結果、php -vでは5.6.30が表示されました。しかしphpmyadmin上では7.1.9が表示されています。やはり通常インストールしたphpを削除しないとだめなのかもしれません